# Motoman IO control service not advertised?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, motoman, motoman-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Motoman FS100: Integrating IO Control Services Help**

Hello! I'm trying to control the IO pins of an Motoman FS100 controller. Single-arm, single-robot group.

**Issue:** ROS services "readSingleIO" and "writeSingleIO" not appearing once launched and connected to robot controller.

Note: Other services like "robot_enable" are still available.

I don't know how to further troubleshoot this issue. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I am following user [gvdhoorn's forked branch, "io_support_rebased"](https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman/compare/kinetic-devel...gavanderhoorn:io_support_rebased) to edit [my own fork of the motoman driver](https://github.com/acbuynak/motoman).

*Versions*

ROS Melodic

MotoROS v1.9.1

*Code* 

Integrated IO over two commits:

1.  [adding ROS services](https://github.com/acbuynak/motoman/commit/8a2cabe67191cca1e976a092bd6e28bbab6d3471)

2.   [adding convenience class](https://github.com/acbuynak/motoman/commit/3ac0c1d9ac1ac93dffdf22c51b914751b270b497)

*Relevant Code from CMakeLists*

from motoman_driver package/CMakeLists

```
add_executable(motoman_motion_streaming_interface_bswap
  src/joint_streaming_node.cpp
  src/joint_trajectory_streamer.cpp
  src/motion_ctrl.cpp
  src/motion_ctrl.cpp
  src/io_ctrl.cpp)
```

from motoman_msgs/CMakeLists

```
add_service_files(
  DIRECTORY
    srv
  FILES
    CmdJointTrajectoryEx.srv
    ReadSingleIO.srv
    WriteSingleIO.srv
)
```

---

*Related Content:*

[ROS Answer: Control I/O of Generic Industrial robot](https://answers.ros.org/question/272675/can-i-control-ports-input-output-of-an-industrial-robot/)

 [ROS Answer: Motoman Digital IO Control](https://answers.ros.org/question/309980/how-can-i-control-digital-ios-for-motoman/)

[Github: Commit for Multi-Robot I/O Read-Write](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/motoman/commit/f764a07308e35175fe68a851c050611c45b7a5ca)

[Google Forum: I/O Control of Motoman DX100](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/swri-ros-pkg-dev/GCC7gP6HJiE/Nhgm31oVBwAJ)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350891/motoman-io-control-service-not-advertised?/) by [acbuynak](https://answers.ros.org/users/51206/acbuynak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you have to move these lines,

```
    // hacking this in here at this place
  io_ctrl_.init(connection);
  this->srv_read_single_io = this->node_.advertiseService("read_single_io",
      &MotomanJointTrajectoryStreamer::readSingleIoCB, this);
  this->srv_write_single_io = this->node_.advertiseService("write_single_io",
      &MotomanJointTrajectoryStreamer::writeSingleIoCB, this);
```

inside this method,

```
bool MotomanJointTrajectoryStreamer::init(SmplMsgConnection* connection, const std::vector<std::string> &joint_names,
    const std::map<std::string, double> &velocity_limits)
{
...
}
```

---

Originally posted by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) with karma: 80 on 2020-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acbuynak](https://answers.ros.org/users/51206/acbuynak/) on 2020-04-29**:
This worked! Thanks!
To clarify for future reviewers, I mistakenly placed the io_ctrl initialization (first code quoted in above answer) into a similar looking bool group that performed a different function.
After moving the placement of the code, everything worked as desired.